# Power series represented in terms of a second power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, where $b\ne0 $
Given the ODE$$ (x^2 +b)y'' +cxy' +\frac{(c-1)^2}{4}y = 0$$
Use a power series about $x_0=0$ to prove that if $c < 0$ is an odd
integer, then there exist a solution to the above ODE which is a polynomial. 
Express your solution in term of a solution $\tilde{y}$ of the ODE$$ (x^2+1)y''+cxy'+\frac{(c-1)^2}{4}=0$$

I have found the solutions to both ODE (the second one is a particular case of the first) and can recognize that  if c is odd and negative , then one of the solutions is a polynomial. However, I am struggling to express the solution $y$ in term of $\tilde{y}$

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the time scale, something like $\tilde y(x)=y(\sqrt{|b|}\,x)$. However, that only gets you to an equation form $(x^2\pm 1)y''(x)+cxy'+\frac{(c-1)^2}4y=0$ for $\tilde y$.